# Should I use IF and AND function? 3 conditions and 3 outcomes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Could someone help me come up with a formula for the conditions below?

[image]

If there is any value greater than **0** on ***col e***, it should return *text 1*

If ***col e*** is **0** and there is any value greater than **0** on ***col c*** and/or ***col d***, it should return *text 2*

If ***col e***, ***col c*** and ***col d*** is **0**, it should return *text 3*

I tried tinkering with a few of other suggestions from other posts, but I couldn't figure out on how to make it work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will offer you this to be put in F1 (assuming the first row is row 1):

```
=IF(E1>0,"text 1",IF(OR(C1>0,D1>0),"text 2","text 3"))
```

with the caveat that it assumes that if E1 is not greater than zero, it will also not be negative or blank (similarly with C1 and D1).  If those are also conditions which should be handled, it will need to be tweaked a bit.

Answer (score 2):

This is according to your requirement

=IF(E1>0,"text 1",IF(AND(E1=0,OR(C1>0,D1>0))),"text 2",if(AND(C1=0,D1=0,E1=0),"text 3","Other text"))

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it: `=IF(E1>0,"text1",IF(AND(E1=0,OR(C1>0,D1>0)),"text2",IF(AND(E1=0,C1=0,D1=0),"text3","")))`

Comment: Condition3 needs to come first as it is more specific than condition1

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 ?? In Condition 3, E1 = 0; in Condition 1, E1 > 0.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 why not just call yourself snake and sydney... :)

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Excel supports the `IFS()` function:

```
=IFS(E1>0,"text 1",OR(C1>0,D1>0),"text 2",TRUE,"text 3")
```

This function allows a nearly direct translation from English into formula.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

```
=IF(E2>0,"text 1",IF(SUM(C2:D2)>0,"text 2","text 3"))
```